# Raising denominator up in frac

Tags: fractions, raise

I want to raise a denominator bit up in `\frac{}{}` but I cannot do it with `\raisebox` while I can push it down with it:

```
$\frac{AAAAAAA}{\raisebox{-3mm}{$AAAA$}}$  % pushes down

$\frac{AAAAAAA}{\raisebox{3mm}{$AAAA$}}$   % no changes
```

**Q1:** What is the reason that `\raisebox` works only one way?

**Q2:** Any simple way to lift a denominator?

[MWE at LatexFiddle](http://latexfiddle.com/#/n3jdgagllmc/10204)

Comment: if you apply `\smash{...}` to the denominator, eliminating its height, `\raisebox` will work, but that will overprint the numerator with the example shown.  it's unclear what you actually want this for.

Comment: please could you provide the example?